# How to retrieve data while keepSynced is true in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm used to using **observeEventType** for prolonged data syncing from Firebase refs. Inside this block I map out the snapshot dictionary to the necessary objects for my app to use. I put these objects in an in-memory Repository.

Recently, I've learned of **keepSynced** as a more convenient way of making sure data is synced/downloaded to the app. But how do I retrieve data from keepSynced Firebase references?

Comment: Establish a listener as normal. There's no different way to read the local cache vs the remote data, no different way to read while offline vs online.

Comment: @Kato what's the use of keepSynced then? **observeEventType** already makes sure that the property you're listening to, say **Value** will be updated for as long as you haven't cancelled that listener.

Comment: The point of keepSynced() is that you may turn listeners on and off. It is essentially a guarantee that the path is always locally persisted, even if no listeners are established at the time you go offline. If your listener is always on there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, **keepSynced** is for situations when you enable offline disk persistence. (It is also documented on the *offline capabilities* section). I learnt about **keepSynced** when I was having problems with disk persistence (firebase was returning me older data, even when I quit the app.) Then I used **keepSynced** and the issue is now solved. When I change data from database, it does not synchronise instantly as it is the case for **observeEventType**. What it does is that, it allows me to refresh the data when it is changed and when **observeSingleEventOfType** is triggered.